# How to open a specific page of a flutter application from another app?

Tags: android, flutter

What I want is,
User while on app B can use my flutter app A. For example when user clicks a button in app B, specific page of app A opens and also app B sends a json object to my app A. After using app A, I want to redirect user to app B again and  along with it I also want to send resultData(json obj) to app B.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, maybe you can use [Deeplink](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking) for communicating between two apps